# Determine what a function has been passed with a void pointer (char int ore Failure)

Tags: c

I passed a void pointer to a function.

Since the evaluation of the function differs a little between int and char, I want to determine in the function whether I get an int or char or another value passed.

How can I do this without the programmer calling this function having to pass a further variable to tell the function what value it is processing.

Vor Exempel:

```
int func (void *value) {
  if (int) {
    //Process
  }
  if else (char) {
    //Process
  }
  else {
    //Failure
  }
```

Comment: This is C. It's `void*` now and there's no going back. You may need a second argument to convey additional context if that's necessary. Traditionally this mess is avoided by writing a macro that pretends to be a function but does the necessary dirty work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I do this without the programmer calling this function having to pass a further variable to tell the function what value it is processing(?)

If you can pass something other than only `void*`, use `_Generic` (since C11) to unburden the caller and steer code to call the needed function.  This approach uses a macro to steer the code, akin to [@tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135677/determine-what-a-function-has-been-passed-with-a-void-pointer-char-int-ore-fail/54137465#comment95102843_54135677) comment.

---

```
void func_int(int x) {
  printf("int: %d\n", x);
}

void func_char(char x) {
  printf("char: %c\n", x);
}

#define func(X) _Generic((X), \
  int: func_int, \
  char: func_char \
)(X)
```

Usage.  No need for the caller to specify one of the implemented types: `int`, `char`.  Just use `func()`.

```
int main() {
  int i = 42;
  char c = 'X';
  func(i);
  func(c);
}
```

Output

```
int: 42
char: X
```

Answer (score 3):

You can not, `void *` is generic and there is no way to know the original type, consider using an `union`

```
enum type {TYPE_INT, TYPE_CHAR);

struct mytype {
    enum type;
    union {
        int *as_int;
        char *as_char;
    } data;
};
```

and pass it to the function:

```
int func(struct mytype *mydata) {
  if (mydata->type == TYPE_INT) {
      return *(mydata->data.as_int);
  } else {
      //Process
  }
  ...
```

Under C11 you can use anonymous `union`s, then you can ommit the `union` name:

```
struct mytype {
    enum type;
    union {
        int *as_int;
        char *as_char;
    };
};
...
  if (mydata->type == TYPE_INT) {
      return *(mydata->as_int);
```

Comment: In other words, you can avoid having a second function parameter, but you cannot avoid requiring the caller to tell the function what type of value is being passed.

Comment: Yes I know, but I can also use a void pointer in c and then about typtef make him an int pointer.

Comment: Yes, of course you can, but you can't know what type is being passed.